# How to use Azure Service Bus Queue as a Server/Client scenario

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-queues

I am trying to rewrite my Server/Client(TCP based connection) program to make it use the Azure Server Bus Queue instead, but I can't figure out how to "organize" Queues and Messages from/to different clients in a way to stop them being read by each other.

Let me start with this scenario:
1 - A client connect to the queue and put in let us say -log in message (Username/Password) into the LOG-IN queue.

2 - Server reading messages found that one of the clients is trying to log in, it reads the message, check the provided details and put results in LOG-IN-RESULT queue.

3 - The client the suppose to read from the LOG-IN-RESULT, but how to guarantee that it is reading its result not another client's?

Sorry for the lack of code, the question is purely about the structure/principal I guess.

Thanks

Comment: By client you mean a user or an application? Estabilishing this is quite an important distinction

Comment: Client is an application that connects to the queue

Comment: Might be a silly question, but why authentication should be done using messaging? There are plenty of other (and perhaps better) ways of achieving the same.

Comment: Ok, please tell me :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I cannot say your queue-based system is suitable for logon scenario. But in your case, I think three options are possible based on Azure.

**1. Use Subscription query (not recommended)**

Azure Service Bus has Topics and Subscriptions capability.
you can create *query* to receive exact same Guid. I did not test performance in this case, but it is capable as below.

`namespaceManager.CreateSubscription("LoginTopic", "LOG-IN-RESULT", new SqlFilter("RequestGuid = '3872-ACD3-38FB-2311-2002'"));`

For more information about Subscription, please read this documentation: [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions/#topics-and-subscriptions)

**2. Use Azure Storage Table**

Azure Table gives query capability so you can use it instantly as below Odata query.

`https://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/LoginTable(PartitionKey='LOG-IN-RESULT',RowKey='3872ACD338FB23112002')`

For more information about Azure Table, please refer this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd894031.aspx).

**3. Use Azure Sql or other rdbms.**

I think you already know. Just Insert and Select.

Comment: I am not sure whether I don't understand your answer or it is not really an answer to my question.

I am trying to use the service bus as a way to communicate between client and server, but I am facing a problem of delivering the message to the correct client.

In regards to Storage Table and RDBMS, they are where to store details as I understand which is not my current problem now.

Comment: @user2410199 // would you try _Subscription_ as I said in No.1? In my understanding, you want to use `Azure Service Bus` definitely in _unordered job_ scenario. For that, `Subscription` could be the only option. Subscription is part of Azure Service Bus.

Comment: I only started trying queue and not topics/subscriptions because it is cheaper. I thought it could be possible to do with queues only. I will try it.

Comment: @user2410199 // if you have Redis server on your site, it could be the another option. It does great pub/sub jobs.

Comment: If I use the topic/subscriptions, I am guessing every client will have to create a topic/subscription when they log in, how do I iterate through topics/subscriptions to check if any new one has been created? How the whole principle work?

Comment: @user2410199 // that's why I said `cannot say your queue-based system is suitable for logon scenario`. you may maintain each receiving task. For example, as this code: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-servicebus-messaging-samples/blob/master/TopicFilters/Program.cs#L129-L132

Comment: From your link "It is DISCOURAGED for applications to routinely set up and tear down topics and subscriptions as a part of regular message processing. Managing topics and subscriptions is a system configuration operation. ". I still would have the same problem, how to manage deliver messages to different clients if they all read from the same topic/subscription? I can't just create and delete on the go.

Comment: @user2410199 // generally for that, a system maintains hash table in memory and a broker accesses to it. You can check Akka framework for Actor model or Azure Service Fabric in Azure-way.

Comment: @user2410199 // in general http scalability sense, a system generates and maintains accessor's token, then processor returns value to exact origin address. It can be implemented simply by (integer token%4=origin instance address).

Comment: I don't understand. I looked for some examples on how to use tokens to write and read per client but I can't find one that matches my needs.

Comment: I think I found a solution. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-servicebus-messaging-samples/tree/master/MessageBrowse. Will check this first and update the question

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an unique identifier for a user who is trying to log in (suppose it is a cookie containing Guid identifier, assigned when user requests a page), let's name it UserId. You can then save the identifier as a part of message id. Then, the client application will only try to read only the messages, which ids contain the specified UserId.

Comment: I thought that in queues you can't choose what to read, first-in-first-out.
How can you selective read from a queue?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you _can't_ filter the message out of the box. The client will process any message it sees in queue. But, my solution is like this:
1. Read the message
2. Check if it is for your client.
3a. If second step is true, process it.
3b. If second step is false, queue the message one more and wait some interval + randomized offset before checking again.

The random part is to prevent multiple clients running in parallel not being able to read their respective messages. 
Sounds plausible?

Comment: It sounds it would work. But I was thinking that the LOG-IN-RESULT queue to be written into by the server application and clients can only read from it, where clients can write to the LOG-IN queue only.

Comment: If you have 1000 clients trying to log in at the same time, the first one will read all 1000 responses and put back 999, then the second will read 999 and put back 998, it doesn't seem a good way of doing this.

Comment: You can queue messages one by one, so it doesn't seem such a bad idea (that's what I'm using in my project, but the use case there differs).

Comment: Yes, I can see this working fine, but to much processing for my case, thank you for your help and time.